# SML - error in finding elements in list

Tags: sml

I'm new to SML. I've written a function which takes 2 int and a list of tuples as input.

```
fun move(x,y,mylist:(int * int)list): NOxNO =
    let
      val counter = ref y-1
    in
      if y=1 then (x,y)
      else (
        while !counter > 0 do (
          if List.exists (fn s => s = (x,!counter)) mylist
          then counter := !counter - 1
          else break
        );
        if !counter = 0 then (x,y) else (x,y-1)
      )
    end
```

I may have syntax error since I'm a beginner. What the function is trying to do is: it will check the list to find all the tuples whose first element is x and second element varies from 1 to y-1 (tuples like this: (x,1) (x,2) ... (x,y-1) ) and if all of them exist in the list it will return (x,y) else (x,y-1). I used a while loop and a counter. counter is set to y-1 at first and in while loop if (x,counter) was found, counter's value will decrease. At last if counter=0 it means we have found all the tuples. After running the program I encountered this error:

```
Caught Error ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some feedback:

1. *(Error)* As Andreas Rossberg said, `break` doesn't exist. But if you use `()`, the loop won't terminate when `y > 1` and the predicate evaluates to false. You probably want to "break" by setting `counter := 0` or `counter := -1`, depending on what you want the subsequent `if !counter = 0 ...` to do.
2. *(Error)* As Andreas Rossberg said, `ref y-1` gives the following type error:

   ```
   ! Toplevel input:
   ! val r = ref y-1;
   !               ^
   ! Type clash: expression of type
   !   int
   ! cannot have type
   !   int ref
   ```

   This is because function application (`ref y`) binds tighter than infix operators (`y-1`). What you mean is `ref (y-1)`, since you can't subtract 1 from a reference.
3. This isn't very comprehensible or robust. I tried to run it in the simplest case I could think of,

   ```
   val test1 = move (1,1,[])
   ```

   But that's a weird base case not handled by the loop. If I change the numbers slightly,

   ```
   val test2 = move (5,6,[])
   ```

   then it returns either `(5,6)` or `(5,5)` depending on what you change `break` into.

Based on your description below the code, here is a suggested implementation, although I'm still not completely certain I understand the use of this function:

```
(* verticalPointsExist (x, y, ps) checks that
 * (x,1), (x,2), ..., (x,y-1) are all in ps. *)
fun verticalPointsExist (_, 0, _) = true
  | verticalPointsExist (x, y, ps) = List.exists (fn p => (x,y) = p) ps
                             andalso verticalPointsExist (x, y - 1, ps)

fun move (x, y, ps) =
    if verticalPointsExist (x, y, ps) then (x,y) else (x,y-1)
```

Considerations I made:

- Use recursion rather than iteration.
- Split the checking part into a helper function, so `move` doesn't do two things.
- Give the functions good names so the code reads more easily. Since I don't know the domain and am really guessing as to whether `y` is some kind of vertical dimension, there are probably even better names out there. (`verticalLineExists`? `verticalPathClear`?) Maybe a more general function will have a better name, e.g. one that took two points and saw that the line is clear between them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `break` in ML. You probably just want to write `()` there. Also, you'll need parens around the argument to `ref` in line 3.